# Vue-Router with dynamically generated aliases (also SSR)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Our business logic allows different types of profile pages (user profiles, company profiles, etc - each with its own template), but the URLs do not discriminate between the types of profiles. All URLs are of the format:

```
mysite.com/{{ profile-vanity-alias }}
```

How would a `vue-router` configuration determine which component to render? e.g.

- `mysite.com/zuckerberg` should render a user profile page
- `mysite.com/facebook` should render a company profile page
- `mysite.com/jeffbezos` does not exist so it should render a 404
- `mysite.com/companies/usa` should render a different page with a list of companies from USA (`/companies/:country?` is a known route that can be hardcoded)

Furthermore, we're also considering to use `vue-ssr` (for SEO); I never really used SSR, so that's something where I wouldn't know where to start - a few pointers would be extremely helpful!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use switch logic to determine which component you need to load, then dynamically load the component.

```
<component v-bind:is="component" />
```

Maybe you can look into detail with this article. https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-make-your-components-dynamic-in-vue-js/

Comment: This doesn't help. The question is how would vue-router decide which page to load if all urls are practically identical (`mysite.com/{{ some-slug }}`)

Answer (score 0):

The route path is obviously something like /:profile. I would have a generic parent component that responds to that route and loads the corresponding profile object (from the API, etc) and, based on some flag or other criteria, it displays the profile component of the person or the one of the company - and here a dynamic component might play a role.
As a short sketch, in the parent component I would have:

```
<div>
   <user-profile v-if="currentObject.isUser" :id="currentObject.id" />
   <company-profile v-if="currentObject.isCompany" :id="currentObject.id" />
</div>
```